# Classification of Text into multiple categories

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am working on a project which needs to determine if a word is a fruit. I have tried several approaches but not satisfied with any of the results. Any suggestions?

My training set looks like this

- **Input**: Apple is a fruit. **Output**: Apple.
- **Input**: Guava is also a fruit **Output**: Guava.
- **Input**: Pineapple is a seasonal fruit **Output**: Pineapple.

Example when running outside training data:

- **Input**: I love all fruits but favorites are guava and apple. **Output**: Guava, Apple

Comment: what have you tried so far. I assume that you just want a ready made solution. Please rephrase your question

Comment: What I have done till now using scikit learn SVM is working well for single label classification , but it's performance is not good at all for multi label . I want some ideas on how to solve my problem. @ArpitSolanki

Comment: do you just need to extract information (_i_._e_. fruit names) from strings? if so, a multilabel classifier may be overkill.

Comment: SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is known as Named Entity Recognition. You can read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) for starters.

A popular library for this is CoreNLP from Stanford. You can read about it on the [Stanford Natural Language Processing Groups website](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).

In order to use it you need to label each token (word) in your training data indicating if it's a fruit or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Soham Chakraborty was this helpful?